# How to use Python to update enterpise geodatabase user connections for layers within an ArcGIS Pro Project map

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, data-source

I tried to use the following code to update the connected database user for layers within an ArcGIS Pro project map. The code runs but it does not change the data sources from one enterprise geodatabase user to another as intended. I previously posted this issue to the GIS Community website but have yet to find an answer--here is the thread for that as well: https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/updateconnectionproperties-is-not-working/m-p/1333516#M68773

```
import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
for m in aprx.listMaps("Mobile_Map"):
    for lyr in m.listLayers():
        if not(lyr.isGroupLayer or lyr.isBasemapLayer):
            print(lyr.connectionProperties["connection_info"])
            try:
                lyr_update = lyr.connectionProperties
                lyr_update['connection_info']['password']='<password>'
                lyr_update['connection_info']['user']='dr'
                lyr.updateConnectionProperties(lyr.connectionProperties, lyr_update)
                         
            except:     
                print("Not an sde database or the database connection does not need to be updated.")
aprx.save()
del aprx
```

Comment: Try making [a copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-and-only-edit-the-copy) of the `lyr.connectionProperties` dict, i.e. `copy.deepcopy(lyr.connectionProperties)`. Alternatively, create a database connection (.sde file) with the updated info and pass that in to `updateConnectionProperties`.

Answer (score 0):

This following code below worked. See full discussion in the ESRI community forum (https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/updateconnectionproperties-is-not-working/m-p/1334613#M68815).

```
import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
for m in aprx.listMaps("Mobile_Map"):
    for lyr in m.listLayers():
        if lyr.supports("connectionProperties"):
            try:
                print(lyr.connectionProperties["connection_info"])
                lyr_update = lyr.connectionProperties
                lyr_update['connection_info']['password']='password'
                lyr_update['connection_info']['user']='dr'
                lyr.updateConnectionProperties(lyr.connectionProperties, lyr_update)

            except Exception as e:
                raise Exception("Not an sde database or the database connection does not need to be updated.") from e
aprx.save()
del aprx
```